# Define outer surface of an Abaqus model and calculate distance integration point-closest surface

Tags: python, abaqus

I have a problem that I am trying to solve for weeks but with no results. After my simulation in Abaqus, once I have exported the stress at each integration points with the respective coordinate, I need to calculate for each integration point the distance from the closest surface. Of course, the geometry can be arbitrarily complex.

What I had in mind was firstly to determine the coordinates of the nodes that belong to the surface of the model (the idea is to do that without determining an a priori surface or set).

### I have found in another thread this piece of code:

```
p = mdb.models[name].parts[name]
surf_nodes = []
for face in p.elementFaces():
    if len(face.getElements()) == 1:
        # Then the face has only one associated element, ie it's on the surface.
        # Get the nodes on the face:
        surf_nodes.extend([node for node in face.getNodes() if node not in surf_nodes])
```

---

The problem is that when I lounch the script I receive this message:

TypeError: MeshFaceArray object is not callable.

Do you know how can I solve this problem? And of course, do you have any idea how to proceed to reach my final goal?

Really thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it does not work, then I can assist you further.

```
p = mdb.models[name].parts[name]
surf_nodes = []
for face in p.elementFaces:
    if len(face.getElements()) == 1:
        surf_nodes.extend([node for node in face.getNodes() if node not in surf_nodes])
```

Comment: It is not working. I mean I get as a result some nodes but these are not only the one on the surface. For example, in my model, I have 8800 nodes and the length of surf_nodes after I launch the script is around 7600. Also picking some nodes from the output of the script you can clearly see that are in the inner part of the model.

Comment: oh ok, does your mesh has also geometry assigned to it? you could check the nodes on geometric faces.

Comment: It was my mistake, it works. Sorry :) thank you very much. I have another question: can I know the elements that contain the identified nodes on the surface?